# RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider for VB Windows/Desktop Application

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config

How to use the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider in a windows/desktop application?
I want to use it in my App.config.
What I see online is using Web.config or an XML file. Or if this is asked before, can someone give me a link so I can study it.

In my project (previously made by another person, I just need to encrypt the App.config).
I have App.config, Form1.vb and mod_connection.vb

In App.config, it has this line.

```
 <add name="SampleMyName" connectionString="Data Source = MyServer; Initial Catalog = MyTable; Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID= MyUser; Password=MyPassword"
```

I tried to encrypt the user ID and password normally using this:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "MY PATH HERE"
```

It's working on the server, but once we shared the exe file to other pc, it's not working. So I'm thinking maybe the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider will help.

Comment: App.config is basically the same thing as Web.config. Whatever you would do to the latter you can do to the former. The DPAPI is machine-specific so you certainly cannot encrypt a file using that on one machine and expect it to work on another. You'd have to perform the encryption as part of the installation process on each machine to use DPAPI.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  sorry I got confused with the installation-thing. Installation of what? Basically when you build a program it will give you that exe file in the Debug folder. That is the file (saved in the server) other user is trying to access in their PC.

Comment: For a Windows app, you build it in VS and it outputs an EXE and a config file. The output in the Debug folder is for debugging. You should build a Release version to distribute. If you want to encrypt the config file on your own machine and distribute the result then you must indeed use RSA. To use DPAPI, you would have to create an application installer and perform the encryption of the config file on the machine that you're installing on, because DPAPI is machine-specific.